# CKEditor entities being converting to HTML in editor display

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

If I have a textarea with the following content inside of it on page load:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
<p>&lt;h1&gt;Hello world&lt;/h1&gt;</p>
```

I apply CKEditor to the textarea, CKEditor renders the content as if both lines were h1 elements, even though one is entities wrapped in a paragraph.

For clarity what I expect to see is:

---

## Hello

`<h1>Hello world</h1>`

---

What I am actually getting is:

---

## Hello

## Hello World

---

Strangely enough, if I type `<h1>Hello world</h1>` into the editor it will produce the entity encoded string in source and display it as expected (printed to display as typed).

Comment: what textarea?  I don't see one there.

Comment: Assume the textarea, I am simply talking about content inside of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because even in textarea you have to encode your HTML. So in fact you should set the content of it to:

```
&lt;h1&gt;Hello&lt;/h1&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&amp;lt;h1&amp;gt;Hello world&amp;lt;/h1&amp;gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

As you can see - Hello world header is encoded twice.

Comment: Doh, I feel like an idiot now. I really thought it was a CKEditor problem.

Comment: Not only you. I at the beginning I thought so too :P